# JBoss classloading when 2 WARs have the same class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, classloader, jboss5.x

I have a web applications A.war which has two servlets `AServlet` and `BServlet`. Both instantiate a helper class `com.mycompany.Foo.class` (this is my own class, not a third party library).

Now I want to split the two servlets into two separate WARs: A.war will have only AServlet and a new B.war will have `BServlet`. `AServlet` will invoke `BServlet` via HTTP GET. Both WARs will have `com.mycompany.Foo.class`. I want to deploy both WARs on the same JBoss instance.

The question is, will there be any classloading issues due to the same class being present in both WARs, and the WARs being deployed on the same JBoss instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't experience any problem. By default the web application class loader works different from the Java2 delegation model: when a web application's needs a class first it will look in the local repositories (that is the classes and libraries in the wEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/libs directories) instead of delegating. So, the configuration you're proposing will work without any problem.

But since both wars will contain the same class, have you considered packaging this class in a jar and place it in the jboss instance lib directory? This way you wouldn't need to include it in all the web applications you deploy in the instance.

Take a look at [Jboss documentation here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/class-loader-howto.html).

Comment: Where did you get that since it is a common class, it needs to be in a jar?  The class is a common class and can be deployed separately in the two applications in the classes/ directory or lib/ <application-library>.jar.

Comment: @Suresh Koya: In the second paragraph I didn't mean that it NEEDS to be in a jar, as you say the class can be placed perfectly in the classes directory of each application, that's ok, and of course it will work. But I was pointing an alternative: placing the class in the JBoss $JBOSS_HOME/server/<instance>/lib directory (in a jar), this way you don't need to copy the class in each application that needs it.

Comment: Thanks Toni for the answer and the pointer to the docs. I will also look into packaging my common classes into a jar and placing it in the instance lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be problems if `com.mycompany.Foo.class` is not exactly the same in both WARs. In JBoss 5.1 per default a class name is unique (unified classloading). That means there can only be one `com.mycompany.Foo.class` and it's shared between both applications. This behavior can be disabled.

Check out (JBossClassLoaderHistory)[https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoaderHistory] for more information.

Comment: Hi Philippe, the unified classloading applies to all Jboss type of deployments, except for WAR files. In the case of WARs, by default Jboss 5.1 will load classes directly from its own WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/libs. So the situation you're describing will happen with EAR files (that's: if you've different versions of the same library in its respective EAR/lib directories, JBoss will just load the first to be deployed, and so one of the ears will use the version of the other, not its own), but you won't have this problem in WAR ones.